# How to add watermark with dropzonejs

Tags: javascript, html, dropzone

I'm using dropzonejs javascript library to upload my images. How can I add watermark with dropzonejs?

Any code and helps would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that using transformFile option of [dropzone](https://www.dropzonejs.com/). I have used [compressorjs](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/compressorjs) library for it. This compresses file and also provides us to draw a watermark.

```
        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myDrop", 
        { 
             paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
             addRemoveLinks: true,
             uploadMultiple: false,
             autoProcessQueue: true,
             parallelUploads: 50,
             maxFilesize: jsonData.maxFileSizeMB, // MB
             acceptedFiles: ".png, .jpeg, .jpg, .gif",
             url: jsonData.uploadUrl,
            
             transformFile: function(file, done){
                 console.log('on transform file: ', file.name);
                     new Compressor(file, {
                         strict: false, 
                         drew: function (context, canvas) { 
                             // draw your watermark to context of the canvas
                         },
                         success: function (result ) 
                         {
                             console.log('success: ready to upload');
                             console.log('result type: ' + result.type);
                             console.log('result size: ' + result.size);
                             // this goes to dropzone on "sending" event
                             done(result);
                         },
                         error: function (err) {
                             console.log(err.message);
                         }, // end error
                     }); // end new Compressor
                 }, // end transformFile
         }); // end new Dropzone
```

Comment: Where do you call `transformFile()` from? Thanks.